# how do I get PL PGSQL error code in a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am writing a PL/PGSQL function and it produces an error. I want to print the error with **RAISE NOTICE** statement but I don't know how to get the error code? What variable holds the last error?

This is my sample code:

```
IF FOUND
THEN
    BEGIN
        insert into app.company(dateinserted,name) values(now(),company_name) returning comnpany_id;
        return company_id;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Insert failed with...';
            return -2;
    END;
ELSE
    RETURN -1;
END IF;
```

This code will return **company_id** if insert was successful and print the error if it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include SQLERRM to get an error message.

Answer (score 5):

```
...
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Insert failed with error code %', SQLSTATE;
...
```

Read more [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)